# Intersection of vector subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be a vector space over a finite field $\mathbb{F}_q$ and $V_i; ~i = 1,2,3$ be three subspaces of $V$ satisfying $V_i \cap V_j = (0)$ for all $i \neq j.$ Can it be proved that $V_1 \cap (V_2 \oplus V_3) = (0),$ $V_2 \oplus V_3$ being the subspace of $V$ generated by $V_2 \cup V_3$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, just draw three distinct lines on the plane $\mathbb R^2$ as your $V_i$'s, which can be easily made to work over $\mathbb F_q$ as well.